# TextInputLayout's setError not showing error

Tags: android

I'm using the following code to display an `EditText` within a `TextInputLayout` so I can use the `setError()` but without using the hint of the `TextInputLayout` :

```
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout android:id="@+id/et_title_wrapper"
            android:hint=" "
            android:layout_marginLeft="32dp" android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="64dp">

        <EditText android:id="@+id/et_title" android:hint="@string/video_title"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:gravity="top" android:paddingTop="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/form_edittext_bottom_margin"
            android:singleLine="true" android:imeOptions="actionNext" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Yet the result is that no error is showing at all.

```
@Override
public void showErrorTitle() {
    Log.i(TAG, "showErrorTitle ");
    etTitleWrapper.setError("You need to add title");
    etTitleWrapper.setErrorEnabled(true);
}
```

I can confirm, using the log, that `showErrorTitle()` is being triggered.

Comment: I executed this code, and it worked for me. It is showing the error message. Also `setErrorEnabled` method need not to be called, because if you pass a text in `setError` method it will be automatically enabled.

Comment: what is the value of @dimen/form_edittext_bottom_margin in your code as i have noted if i increase this margin  error message will be clipping at bottom.

Comment: @DivyangPanchal yes, that might be the problem. when i executed this code I removed that line because OP didnt mentioned the dimen value.

Comment: dont use margin to edittext instade use it with textinputLayout. this working fine for me

Comment: you are right - margin was the problem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This should work but you can change the order and see.

Change the order,

```
etTitleWrapper.setErrorEnabled(true);
etTitleWrapper.setError("You need to add title");
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add this line in your TextInputLayout xml**

> `app:errorEnabled="true"`

**Edit:**

```
    <EditText android:id="@+id/et_title" android:hint="@string/video_title"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:gravity="top" android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/form_edittext_bottom_margin"
        android:singleLine="true" android:imeOptions="actionNext" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>`
```